# How To Make a Quarter Circle using AutoLayout

Tags: swift, geometry, autolayout, uibezierpath

How can I make a quadrant (quarter-circle) like the one below, using Auto-Layout in Swift? I understand that `UIBezierPath` is required but I can't seem to get it to work.

[image]

Comment: Please update your question with your attempt to make this work. Clearly explain what issues you are having with your attempt.

Comment: “ How can I make a quadrant (quarter-circle) like the one below, using Auto-Layout in Swift?” You can’t. That’s like asking how you can do your taxes with a garden spade. Auto-layout lets you control the size and positioning of views, and doesn’t have much to do with your question. See DonMag’s answer for how you can draw a filled quarter circle using a CAShapeLayer and a UIBezierPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick, simple example:

```
class QuarterCircleView: UIView {
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // only add the shape layer once
        if layer.sublayers == nil {
            let lay = CAShapeLayer()
            lay.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            layer.addSublayer(lay)
        }
        if let lay = layer.sublayers?.first as? CAShapeLayer {
            let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
            let bez  = UIBezierPath()
            bez.move(to: center)
            bez.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: bounds.width * 0.5, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: .pi * 1.5, clockwise: true)
            bez.close()
            lay.path = bez.cgPath
        }
    }
    
}
```

Note: you really should show what you've tried when posting a question. Search for `CAShapeLayer` and read some tutorials.

Comment: Nice answer. (Voted). Note that if you’re creating a custom subclass of UIView you can override the static var `layerClass` and cause the view’s content layer to be a CAShapeLayer. That way you don’t have to create a second layer to hold the shape. Also note that if your view ever changes size/shape (due to a device rotation, for example) the shape won’t be updated unless you detect size changes and update the shape in your shape layer.

Comment: Nevermind my second point. I see you generate your path in layoutSubviews.

Comment: Also your answer only fills a quarter of the target view with a quarter circle. I think the OP wants to make the radius of the quarter circle be the full size of the view..

Comment: @DuncanC - valid points... I was trying to give the OP some direction, so they could work on it further. If the sole purpose is that one shape, yes, override `layerClass` ... of course, one would also (likely) add various public properties such as fillColor, border, "which quadrant," inset from edges, etc, etc ,etc.

Comment: Great solution! I just needed it to fill the entire bounds of the view

Comment: Good point about perhaps needing a more complex view. The `layerClass` trick is good to know though, so I wanted to get it documented.

Comment: @K.Janjuha you should accept this answer since it was the first one to answer your question. (My answer was a minor update to DonMag’s.)

Comment: All done thanks Duncan

Answer (score 1):

Modifying DonMag's answer slightly to make the view's layer a CAShapeLayer so we don't have to worry about adding a sublayer or checking for an existing sublayer:

```
class QuarterCircleView: UIView {

    // By adding this static var, we can change the type of our view's  layer (in this case, to a CAShapeLayer)
    static override var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }

    // This lets us use the view's layer as a CAShapeLayer without type casting.
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer {
        return self.layer as! CAShapeLayer
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    }

    // Every time we update our subviews, also regenerate our shape layer's path.
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // We want a quarter-circle centered on the lower right of teh view.
        let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.maxX, y:bounds.maxY)
        let bez  = UIBezierPath()
        bez.move(to: center)

        // As long as our view is square, the below isn't needed, but let's be sure.
        let radius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height)
        bez.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: .pi * 1.5, clockwise: true)
        bez.close()
        shapeLayer.path = bez.cgPath
    }

}
```

Mine looks like this: (With a 1-pixel border around the view so you can see its bounds: [image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was after! Thank you! I just have one question. How can I now add a border to the blue segment area only? Thanks Duncan

Comment: Nevermind I got it

```swift
shapeLayer?.lineWidth = 5
shapeLayer?.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
```